# conditional statement if wordpress theme block is empty then hide block

Tags: themes, block-editor

I need a conditional statement for the following for the WordPress block theme I am working on.

```
if <!-- wp:group {"tagName":"main"} --> is empty then display none.
```

Comment: sounds like this is not yet possible https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/32939

Comment: Sad. Thanks anyways @will